# Eager and Lazy Loading in Nested Related Records

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In Yii2 Rest Controller i use

```
$customers = Customer::find()->with('orders.items')->all();
```

it returns me the data of `customers` along with `orders` and nested `items`.
which i did not want.

i want only to return the `items` data without `orders` data with `customers` data.

how to do it ?

Comment: What you want is a list of customers with its items (not the order(s))?

Comment: Your question is not clear  ..  Update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: If `Customer` has a direct relation with items, you can do that, otherwise you'll have to go through `orders` relation.

Comment: good luck mate this ain't happening as `items` are against `orders`, not `customer` but the thing is why you are trying to do that? that is why you have to add a complete question and define your actual problem that you are trying to solve maybe there is some other way of doing it rather that you are trying to do

Comment: you could create a custom serializer for your Customer model which creates an array of the fields you do want and use that in your rest controller.